# a weird string prefix appears when strcat the str

Tags: c

here is my code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int mypow(int s, int times); //only a pow function return a int

int main(void)
{
  int a;
  char str[80];
  char result[80];
  int cur;
  int input = 152;
  int len = 3;
  sprintf(str, "152 = ");
  strcat(result, str);
  for (a = 0; a < len; a++)
  {
    cur = input % 10;
    input = input / 10;
    if (a == 0)
    {
      sprintf(str, "%i", cur);
      strcat(result, str);
      sprintf(str, " + ");
      strcat(result, str);
    }
    else if (a < len - 1)
    {
      sprintf(str, "%i*%i", cur, mypow(10, a));
      strcat(result, str);
      sprintf(str, " + ");
      strcat(result, str);
    }
    else
    {
      sprintf(str, "%i*%i", cur, mypow(10, a));
      strcat(result, str);
    }
  }
  puts(result);
  return 0;
}
```

I hope to put the below code onto terminal

```
152 = 2 + 5*10 + 1*100
```

but I got such probably results

```
E:\c>e:\c\hello.exe
X152 = 2 + 5*10 + 1*100

E:\c>e:\c\hello.exe
X?52 = 2 + 5*10 + 1*100

E:\c>e:\c\hello.exe
X?52 = 2 + 5*10 + 1*100
```

what happened in this process

Comment: As `a` is not needed outside of the scope of the loop, I suggest locally scoping it to the loop. `for (int a = 0; a < len; a++) { ...`

Comment: Also, as both `str` and `result` are limited to 80 characters, you will make your life easier using `strncat` to ensure you don't have buffer overflows.

Comment: @Chris `strncat()` tricky to use as its size parameter is the size limit of what to append and not the size of the destination.

Answer (score 5):

You use

```
sprintf(str, "152 = ");
strcat(result, str);
```

before you have initialized `result`.

Because `result` is not initialized, its contents is *indeterminate* (look at it as random or garbage).

To use `strcat` both strings needs to be proper null-terminated strings.

The easiest solution is to use `strcpy` to copy the literal string directly into `result`:

```
strcpy(result, "152 = ");
```

Or possibly skip that and initialize `result` at definition:

```
char result[80] = "152 = ";
```

Comment: Or initialize both `str` and `result` with `char str[80] = {0};` and `char result[80] = {0};`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in line

```
strcat(result, str);
```

You concatenate `str` to `result`, but you do not initialize `result` variable, so there is some garbage in there in the start.

You should use `strcpy()`

```
strcpy(result, str);
```

Answer (score 1):

We all come here (SO) to learn and to grow.

Give this a try, then study how it functions.

You will REALLY benefit from learning/using standard library functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    char result[ 128 ]; // be generous!!
    int input = 152;
    int pos = sprintf( result, "%d = ", input ); // magic can happen

    for( int ind = 1; input; input /= 10, ind++ ) {
        char *join = " + ";
        if( input < 10 ) join = "";
        pos += sprintf( result + pos, "%i*%.*s%s", input % 10, ind, "10000000000", join );
    }

    puts( result );

    return 0;
}
```

The main 'trick' here is that `sprintf()` returns the number of characters it has written to the destination. By keeping track of those (accumulating), there's no need for intermediary buffers and lots of calls to "strcat/strcpy".

If you can write LESS code to do the job, you are making progress!

EDIT:

Inspired by positive recommendations from another, here is a version using a bit less code.

```
int main( void ) {
    char result[ 128 ], *at = result, *join = ""; // be generous!!
    int input = 152;

    at += sprintf( at, "%d = ", input ); // magic can happen
    for( int ind = 1; input; input /= 10, join = " + " )
        at += sprintf( at, "%s%i*%.*s", join, input % 10, ind++, "10000000000" );

    puts( result );

    return 0;
}
```

While the string of zeros is finite, the buffer size being written to is also very small... This is purely for fun...

And, for those with good eyes who prefer descending order:

```
int main( void ) {
    char str[128],*p=str,*join="",*pow="10000",*in="54321";
    int rev=strlen(in);
    
    p+=sprintf(p,"%s = ",in); // magic can happen
    while(*in)p+=sprintf(p,"%s%c*%.*s",join,*in++,rev--,pow),join=" + ";
    puts( str );

    return 0;
}

// Output:
54321 = 5*10000 + 4*1000 + 3*100 + 2*10 + 1*1
```

Finally, an counter example to show there is a massive cost to be paid for **overdoing it**... The following compiles and gives the desired output, but is (to most readers) *impenetrable*. Do NOT! write code like this except for your own amusement.

```
int main( void ) {
    char in[] = "123456", obuf[] = " + x*10000000";
    printf( "%s = ", in );
    int rev = strlen( in ) + 2;
    for( int o=3, i=0; (obuf[3] = in[i]) != '\0'; o=0, i++ )
        printf( "%.*s", rev+3-o-i-(in[i+1]?0:2), obuf+o );

    return 0;
}
/* Output
123456 = 1*100000 + 2*10000 + 3*1000 + 4*100 + 5*10 + 6
*/
```